# Phonegap Socket.io Chat

Tags: node.js, cordova, socket.io, chat

I am trying to build a phonegap chat application using socket.io, now I understand how it would work using the express Framework (http://socket.io/get-started/chat/), but does anyone know how to build the same thing with phonegap?

Answer (score 2):

If you build your client side content in Phonegap, you can simply use socket.io as a cross-browser WebSocket, as described in the [socket.io documentation](http://socket.io/docs/#using-it-just-as-a-cross-browser-websocket). This means that you will not be serving anything like you would normally do in a framework or in socket.io. Instead you set up your Node.js server as described in the linked example. So the only communications you do with the server are the pieces of information you need to share between clients.

Doing this you can build all your logic with the basic socket.io building blocks of emits, rooms, and callbacks, without having to worry about how you are going to serve up the content.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Socket.io can be applied on PhoneGap. 
For example, You have a Node.js Socket.io app that includes index.js(your server code) and index.html(your client code) and assume that you uploaded your app to the internet, and the url is like https://www.your-web-site.com/

To convert your Socket.io app into a PhoneGap app, you don't need your index.js(your server code). You just need your index.html, and you need to modify your src path and Socket.io connection string in index.html, like this;

Firstly, change `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` into

`<script src="https://www.your-web-site.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

Secondly, change `var socket = io();` into

```
var socket = io.connect("https://www.your-web-site.com");
```

After that you can convert this new index.html code into a PhoneGap app.